# How to avoid deadlock : id taking same thread instead of new one

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, deadlock

I have 20 records which I have send it through thread. Each record has to take new thread
I have application_number and Queue_Id .  The application number is same for all the records and Queue_Id is different .
When I run the application it works fine for 2 to 3 records,after that the 4 record takes the same thread as of first record.The queue_id is different for each record.

Here is my Output

```
Application _Number          Queue_ID      Thread_ID
    **23**                      *2*            20
    **23**                      *3*            24
    **23**                      *7*            25
    **23**                      *5*            30
    **23**                      *9*            25
    **23**                      *6*            27
```

Bold indicates : Application_Number
Italic indicates : Queue_ID
Normal : thread_Id

For Queu_Id 7 and 9 it takes same thread instead of taking new one.

Your Help should be appreciated.
Thanks in advance

Comment: It would really help us to help you if you would post your code.

Comment: Also, it's possible that queue 7 was completed on thread 25 and when queue 9 came up thread 25 was the next available thread in the pool.

Comment: @Tim Thanks for your response . Yes it may but the thing is when thread completes , we send a msg which is unique  for every queue_id, By accessing same thread 7 and 9 are sending a same msg means it is accessing the same thread.

Comment: How are threads associated to queues? One thread by queue, a pool of threads...?

Comment: Each queue has one thread

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you are trying to accomplish or how your app. works, but it seems fine that you'll see duplicate thread IDs. If the app. is coded sane, it should be fine to reuse threads.